# Confusion with pointer program (c programming)

Tags: c, pointers

When compiling this program I receive an output that I would've never expected. When I reviewed this program I expected the outcome of *pointer* to be still "Hello, world!" because to my knowledge *pointer* was never affected by *pointer2*. Yet, my output shows that when *pointer* is printed it contains *pointer2*'s string "y you guys!". How is this so?? Thanks!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str_a[20];
    char *pointer;
    char *pointer2;

    strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
    pointer = str_a;
    printf(pointer);

    pointer2 = pointer + 2;
    printf(pointer2);
    strcpy(pointer2, "y you guys!\n");
    printf(pointer);
}
```

Output

```
Hello, world!
llo, world!
Hey you guys!
```

Comment: pointers point to memory addresses. That being said, `pointer` is pointing to the base address of `str_a` and pointer2 is pointing 2 bytes ahead of the base address of `str_a`. So, you are affecting `str_a` data each time you're accessing any of the pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a single area of memory, the array `str_a`.

After `strcpy` call and the assignments to `pointer` and `pointer2` is looks something like this in memory:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----------------------+
| H | e | l | l | o | , |   | w | o | r | l | d | ! | \n | \0 | (uninitialized data) |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----------------------+
^       ^
|       |
|       pointer2
|
pointer
```

The variable `pointer` points to `str_a[0]` and `pointer2` points to `str_a[2]`.

When you call `strcpy` with `pointer2` as the destination, you change the memory that `pointer2` points to, which is the same array that `pointer` also points to, just a couple of character further along.

Comment: Oooh, nice display. Can't top that. <g>